# WordPress favicon - is displayed only in backend

Tags: html, wordpress, favicon

Favicon is set in the divi template. However, it is only displayed in the backend. In the source code is visible too, so probably its not cache problem:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" />
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Site is example.com

Comment: I can't find those code strings in head tag of your site.

Comment: There are - line 198 https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2021/07/01/kkD2.png

Comment: I mean that your lines of code with icons must be in head tag.

Comment: it is inside head tag. If you in source code search </head> this icons are over that

Comment: No, on main page of your site tadesco.org I can't find any rel="icon" link

Comment: https://ctrlv.link/shots/2021/07/02/GAOr.png is end of your head tag

Answer (score 0):

I added to child theme to header file:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-smiling-sun-1.png" />
```

Seems, it work now.